# BigQuery: clustering column with millions of cardinality

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table, partitioned by date (for everyday there is one partition).
I would like to add various columns sometimes populated and sometimes missing and a column for a unique-id.
The data need to be searchable through a unique id. The other use case is to aggregate per column.
This unique id will have a cardinality of millions per day.
I would like to use the unique-id for clustering.
Is there any limitation on this? Anyone has tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a valid use case to enable clustering on an id column, the amount of values shouldn't cause any limitations.